# If None as a type hint is replaced by type(None) why do they behave differently while annotating?

Tags: python, annotations, type-hinting, nonetype

I found out from [`docs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases):

> Note that `None` as a type hint is a special case and is replaced by `type(None)`.

However, I don't find this to be the case in practice (Using Python 3.8.5, iPython 7.16.1). For example:

- If I use `type(None)` to annotate a variable:

```
In [1]: class Foo:
   ...:    a: int
   ...:    b: str
   ...:    c: type(None)

In [2]: Foo.__annotations__
Out[2]: {'a': int, 'b': str, 'c': NoneType}

In [3]: for k, v in Foo.__annotations.__.items():
   ...:    print(f'Default for {k} -> {v()!r} {v}')

Default for a -> 0 <class 'int'>
Default for b -> '' <class 'str'>
Default for c -> None <class 'NoneType'>
```

- Whereas, using simply `None` produces error:

```
In [4]: class Foo:
   ...:     a: int
   ...:     b: str
   ...:     c: None

In [5]: Foo.__annotations__
Out[5]: {'a': int, 'b': str, 'c': None}

In [6]: for k, v in Foo.__annotations.__.items():
   ...:    print(f'Default for {k} -> {v()!r} {v}')

Default for a -> 0 <class 'int'>
Default for b -> '' <class 'str'>
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-40-d9b0ce31b437>", line 2, in <module>
    print(f'Default for {k} -> {v()!r} {v}')

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

So what is happening? What does the line from the doc mean? Is it specifically for the linters and does not affect the actual annotations? If so why not enforce `type(None)` while hinting, or convert `None` to `type(None)` in the annotations dict as well, instead of having two different behaviors in almost similar contexts? I guess this is the reason they are bringing back `types.NoneType` in 3.10?

Comment: Because `None()` will raise an error.

Comment: Yes, I do understand that is why it's raising the error, however why the ambiguity in the docs?

Comment: I mean am I misinterpreting something? Or the docs are wrong (which is highly unlikely).

Comment: The docs sound misleading. The type annotation is not literally replaced. It's just that "it is understood as a convention" that to annotate for `type(None)` then using `None` is acceptable. This is purely for convenience

Comment: [PEP484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#using-none) is much clearer: "When used in a type hint, the expression None is considered equivalent to type(None)". Pity they didn't use the same language in the docs.